# How to enable and fix preview page on link hover?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

How can I unable website preview feature on all of the links in my web page? That is when the user moves the mouse over any link in the page, I want to show a simple pop up window which loads the page in link. I tried doing it on my own with help of Google and stackoverflow. But result got something like this -

[image]

(ACTUAL PAGE LINK RENDERING)

[image]

How should I fix this? I wanted to have it similar to Google instant preview.

Here is my code - (website links are fetched from web service)

html file

```
 <div class="text-result" *ngIf="Display('all')">
                <div *ngFor="let item of items$|async" class="result">
                    <div class="frame">
                        <script>
                            $(".head-link").mouseover(function() {
                                $(this).children(".tooltip").show();
                            }).mouseout(function () {
                                $(this).children(".tooltip").hide();
                            });
                        </script>
                        <div class="title">
                            <a href="{{item.link}}" class="head-link">{{item.title}}
                            <iframe id="tooltip" src="{{item.link}}"></iframe>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="link">
                        <p>{{item.link}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        {{item.pubDate|date:'fullDate'}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

css file

```
.head-link {
  color: #069;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tooltip {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the code working. Could you setup a jsfiddle for us? Additionally, lots of sites disallow being viewed in an iframe for security reasons, so maybe that's your trouble. Any errors in your chrome console?

Comment: No errors in chrome console. There is a lot of code. So, I can't put jsfiddle. These links are fetched from a web service.

Comment: A JS fiddle should only include exactly what you need to replicate the problem, you don't need to put all your code in there, just what is needed to replicate the problem.

Comment: @Adam I have setup the jsfiddle for you. Check the comment, I have done in your answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[I setup a minimal JS fiddle for you, and I believe I resolve the issue.](https://jsfiddle.net/fxdf1xfu/)

A summary of my changes is:

- Your iframe has an `id=tooltip`, when you are referencing it as `.tooltip`, so I changed it to `class=tooltip`.
- Your jQuery script has to appear after the elements on the page that are used by it, so I moved the script tags to the bottom of the `class=text-results` div.

Two notes:

- First, this isn't an Angular 2 problem, you are using Angular 2 in your project, but the problem is with your jQuery code.
- Second, you really should avoid using jQuery to solve your problems within an Angular 2 project. Angular 2 has the capability to solve this problem without needing to include jQuery. Mixing jQuery and Angular 2 will result in messy and hard to understand code, you are much better off trying to solve this problem using only Angular 2.

Comment: Thanks Adam, for giving time to my question : ) I'll also, try to do it with Angular 2.

Comment: Glad I could help. Good luck!

Comment: Hey Adam! Tried solving it using Angular 2. It will be very much helpful for me if you can check my code. Here my jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/harshit98/nusL4cbL/ .Angular does not allow dynamically binding to iframe's `src`. I  need to inject `DomSanitizer` and use the `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl` method. How should I do it?